# update state on each iteration in react

Tags: reactjs, loops, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am new to react, and I want to recreate the hacker effect like here: [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-beaver-k1xh3j?file=/src/App.js:53-77)

For that, I want to update the word (state) that is showing in each iteration of a for loop.

It's also worth mentioning that the update function will be called inside a `setTimout`, on each **iteration**. I know that the state is updated **asynchronously** and that react optimizes those changes under the hood. But I want to by-pass that.

This is what I tried:

```js
myName = 'Test'

for (
 let letterPosition = 0;
 letterPosition < myName.length, letterPosition++;

) {
 for (let numberOfIteration = 0; numberOfIteration < 3, numberOfIteration++; ) {
  setTimeout(() => {
   setName(...something)
  }, 100)
 }
}
```

The loop iterates for each letter of the `myName` var, and updates the state 3 times for each letter. But The state only updates at the end.

Comment: Your problem is probably no batching hut the constant timeout. Try `100 * letterPosition`